# how to specify given model on Eviews?

Tags: software

I am still struggling to estimate my model on Eviews. I know it should be really simplistic to do it,but without in depth Eviews knowledge it can be rather tricky. For instance, looking at the highlighted bit in the file , how would you estimate in Eviews? I will be really grateful if any of you could help me on that as it is basically the only thing holding me back. For some reason I could not upload the picture , however, here is the link for the model : http://s8.postimg.org/o4z6ln8f9/Untitled.png.

Comment: You may follow Eviews user's guide.